# VBA to move a text box works, and then stops working

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

This code should find an ordinary/basic text box on a worksheet and then move it left. Then go to the next sheet and do the same thing. Do until the last sheet.

It works (as I cycle through it using F8), but then the next sheet it says **the object doesn't support this property of method**.

I've no idea why this is happening.

```
Dim I As Integer
Dim txBox As Shape
Set txBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Text Box 1")


For I = 1 To Worksheets().Count
    Worksheets(I).Activate
    txBox.Select
    **Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 586.5**

Next I

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the text box is named "Text Box 1" on each sheet, you just need to move the `Set txBox =` line inside your `For` loop. Otherwise, `txBox` refers just to the text box on the sheet that was active when you started your macro. Since `txBox` is no longer on the active sheet, `Selection` does not refer to `txBox`, but more likely a cell and not necessarily a text box, hence the "Object doesn't support this property or method" error. The code below will hopefully do the trick or at least get you moving in the right direction.

```
Dim I As Integer
Dim txBox As Shape

For I = 1 To Worksheets().Count
    Worksheets(I).Activate
    Set txBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Text Box 1")
    txBox.Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.IncrementLeft 586.5
Next I
```

**Edit:**
As an aside, you can improve the performance of your macro by avoiding all the `.Select`, `.Activate`, `Selection` calls.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim txBox As Shape

For Each ws in Worksheets
    Set txBox = ws.Shapes("Text Box 1")
    txBox.IncrementLeft 586.5
Next ws
```

Comment: Thank you. I've used your performance improving code example and it's works great.